# Why is $\{\{1\}\}$ not equal to $\{1,\{1\}\}$?

Tags: discrete-mathematics, elementary-set-theory

> Determine whether each of these pairs of sets are equal$$A = \{\{1\}\} \qquad \qquad B = \{1, \{1\}\}$$

I believe $A$ is equal to $B$ because all elements in $A$ are in $B$, but the answer says that it's not.

Comment: A has one element but B has two.

Comment: Are you asking if A is a subset of B or if A is equal to B?

Comment: @JohnDouma Aren't A is a subset of B and A is equal to B the same thing?

Comment: 1 is not the same as the set containing 1.

Comment: If being a subset is the same as being equal, then all sets are empty.

Comment: Aren't A a subset of B the same as A equal B? What ?!?!?! absolutely of course not! A equal B means A and B have the same elements. A subset B means all of the elements of A are in B but not nescessarily are all elements of B in A. In the is case they *can't* be equal because they don't have the same elements. B has 1 as an element but A does not. $B \not \subset A $. For $A=B $ then **both** $A\subset B $ **and** $B \subset A $.

Comment: @fleablood Thx for clearing out the confusion :)

Comment: The answer actually depends on whether $1=\{1\}$ or $1\ne\{1\}$. The former would make $1$ a *Quine atom*, which is an entity you will not want to encounter in the set theory you learn.

Comment: @Hagen: Unless you learn about permutation models and ZFA. In that case, Quine atoms are very useful.

Comment: @AsafKaragila I did not want to imply that *you* might not be interested in them. Rather, that the OP might lead a much happier life by postponing this encouner a bit :)

Answer (score 28, accepted):

You're correct that all elements in $A$ are in $B$, but not the other way around - $B$ includes the element $1$, but $A$ only has $\{1\}$. Think of it like boxes - $B$ is a box that includes one item and also a box that itself contains one item; $A$ is just a box containing a box containing an item.

Comment: And now think about this: does the box of all the boxes that don't contain themselves contain itself? Hahaha

Answer (score 47):

Think of $A$ as a bag which contains within it another smaller bag with a one in it.

$A=\underbrace{\{~~~~~~~\overbrace{\{1\}}^{\text{second bag}}~~~~~~~~\}}_{\text{first bag}}$

On the other hand, $B$ is a bag which contains in it not only a second bag with a one in it, but *also* a one which is loose.

$B=\underbrace{\{~~~~~~~~\overbrace{\{1\}}^{\text{second bag}}~~~~~\overbrace{1}^{\text{this too}}~~~~~~~\}}_{\text{first bag}}$

$1\in B$ but $1\not\in A$.  There is no "loose 1" in $A$, there is only a *bag with a one in it* in $A$.

Thus, $A\neq B$